# Changing URL pattern in Django so it doesn't show app name

Tags: django, django-urls

I've got a folder/app named "projects" and there I want to make a new site there, named, let's say, "cheese".
In my urlpatterns in urls.py in projects folder I've got

```
path('cheese/', views.cheese, name='cheese')
```

but the whole URL looks like ***domain.co/projects/cheese***

I'd like to omit that *projects* in URL, so it could just be ***domain.co/cheese***

Those URL-things are kinda hard to understand for me and as I couldn't properly name my problem, I couldn't find a solution out there, though I believe there must be some.

Comment: Is this `urls.py` within the `cheese` app or witin the main folder (the one that contains `settings.py`)?

Comment: the main folder. maybe I shouldn't call cheese a "project", let's rather name it just some website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of having an `app` inside another `app` is kinda weird, but anyways, that won't enforce the inner app's urls to be like `<outer_app>/<inner_app>/...` if you set the url patterns correctly.

Basically, you've got `domain.co/projects/cheese` because, you include your project's app urls as:

```
# main urls.py file for your project


path('projects/', include('projects.urls'))
```

and in your project's urls file you have:

```
# projects/urls.py


path('cheese/', include('projects.cheese.urls'))
```

So if you want to have the `cheese` urls as `domain.co/cheese`, simply add the `include` to the **main** url file:

```
# main urls.py file for your project


path('projects/', include('projects.urls'))
path('cheese/', include('projects.cheese.urls'))
```

Comment: sorry, it's not an app within an app, I just missnamed it here - mea culpa, already edited post. but I guess this doesn't change the whole solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "**new site**", shouldn't it be an app within django's terminology? anyways, if you have a _custom_ `urls.py` for your cheese, you should `include` that in the **main** `urls.py` file (the one that is located inside the initial project directory)

Comment: I meant subpage, but terminology shouldn't be that important in this case, is it?

Comment: I got it. So you have something like `path('projects/', include('projects.urls'))` in your main `urls.py` file, right? That will add a **/projects/** prefix to all the urls included inside your `projects/ursl.py`. So if you want to remove that prefix, you can use `path('', include('projects.urls'))` in your main `urls.py` file and _explicitly_ add the "projects" in those urls you wish.